# Average of random variables from two Poisson distributions?

Tags: mean, poisson-distribution, matlab, sum

I'm lost with a very simple question of finding the average of random variables from two Poisson distributions. I know that if $X\backsim Pois(L1)$ and $Y\backsim Pois(L2)$, then $X+Y\backsim Pois(L1+L2)$.

I have a queue open for nine hours daily with an average of four persons in it every given minute for seven hours and an average of 20 persons in it every given minute for two hours. So I can't simply pair the $X$ from four persons per minute with $Y$ from 20 persons per minute. I suppose I could pair two hours of $X\backsim Pois(4)$ and two hours of $Y\backsim Pois(20)$ and simulate 240 samples with MatLab's `poissrnd(24)` to get the number of persons in the queue for each minute of 4/9 hours but I don't know what would I do with the remaining five hours of $X\backsim Pois(4)$? Maybe I could pair four hours of $X\backsim Pois(4)$ with four hours of $Z = X+Y\backsim Pois(24)$ and simulate 480 samples with `poissrnd(28)` but that would leave me one remaining hour of $X\backsim Pois(4)$. Would it be correct to take 480 samples with `poissrnd(28)` and then simply add 60 samples with `poissrnd(4)`?

After finding out how to simulate the samples I take the average of them. The question is, how do I simulate the random samples representing the number of people in the queue during the day with this information? Is `mean(480*poissrnd(28) + 60*poissrnd(4))` what I am looking for? Assumption is, that Poisson distribution is the right one for the job so I'll use that.

Comment: Could $X$ correspond to the whole five hours, $Y$ to the other four hours and the average be $(X+Y)/9$?

Comment: A satisfying answer was posted to MathWorks site: https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1844008-average-of-random-variables-from-two-poisson-distributions